# What is meant by "term" for presidency in US?

Tags: united-states, president, presidential-election, presidential-term

When it is said a single term or two term president then does it means that the president was elected for the office of President one time or two time or did the president was in his position for 4 years or 8 years respectively.

So if the president is in his 2nd term after getting elected and he/she resigns in the middle so will the president still be considered to be a 2- term president and if not , can the president still run for the office again ?

Answer (score 1):

The 22nd Amendment (Section 1) reads as follows:

> No person shall be elected to the office of the President more than twice, and no person who has held the office of President, or acted as President, for more than two years of a term to which some other person was elected President shall be elected to the office of the President more than once. But this article shall not apply to any person holding the office of President when this article was proposed by the Congress, and shall not prevent any person who may be holding the office of President, or acting as President, during the term within which this article becomes operative from holding the office of President or acting as President during the remainder of such term.

In the scenario you cite, because the President had been elected twice, they would be ineligible to stand for a third time.

Comment: But someone who had been elected Vice President, and then had become President after more than two years, could run for two full terms.  E.g. Lyndon Johnson, who became President after Kennedy was killed in 1963, elected in 1964, and could have legally run again in 1968, except that his unpopularity made winning seem unlikely.

Comment: Correct.  If Kennedy had been assassinated a year earlier, then Johnson would not have been eligible to run for a second full term, as he would have served for more than two years of the previous term.